# Why is executable found without a full path despite its location not in search path?

Tags: bash, sudo, pam, environment-variables, path

This question is about understanding the reason(s) behind a perceived inconsistency between documented and actual behavior when calling an executable through *sudo*. When the *secure_path* option is enabled (default on my system), the search path behave as expected. But when the option is disabled, something strange happens: an executable in `/usr/local/bin` can be reached without a fully qualified path name despite its location not being in the search path.

### System Information

The following software is currently installed on my system:

```
## Yeah... still haven't migrated to Alma
[me@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111

[me@localhost ~]$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.29
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.29
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.29

[me@localhost ~]$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
```

PAM does not set or update the value of the PATH variable on my system:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ grep --recursive 'pam_env\.so' /etc/pam.d
/etc/pam.d/fingerprint-auth:auth        required      pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/smartcard-auth:auth        required      pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/su:auth        required    pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/password-auth:auth        required      pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/system-auth:auth        required      pam_env.so

[me@localhost ~]$ sudo cat /etc/security/pam_env.conf /etc/environment | grep PATH
# be useful to be set: NNTPSERVER, LESS, PATH, PAGER, MANPAGER .....
#PATH       DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin\
```

My `/etc/sudoers` file sets a *secure_path* value for all sudoers:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo grep --recursive secure_path /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d
/etc/sudoers:Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Bash defaults to the following PATH value:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ env --ignore-environment bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Finally, I am connected to the system through SSH, whose `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contains this line:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo grep PATH /etc/sshd_config
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

### Replication Procedure

To replicate, I first create a dummy script and install it in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ cat > dummy <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo 'Found!'
EOF

[me@localhost ~]$ sudo install --owner=root --group=root --mode=755 dummy /usr/local/bin
```

I verify that the search path works as expected when not using *sudo*:

```
## The /usr/local/bin location is part of my search path
[me@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

## This is expected
[me@localhost ~]$ dummy
Found!
```

And using *sudo*, no surprise here either:

```
## Sudo's secure_path value
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

## This is expected
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other which dummy
which: no dummy in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

## This too, of course
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other dummy
sudo: dummy: command not found

## Indeed, a fully qualified path name is required
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other /usr/local/bin/dummy
Found!
```

Then, I disable *secure_path* (careful here! use of *visudo* is advised), either by commenting the line out in `/etc/sudoers` or by creating a file `/etc/sudoers.d/local` with the following lines:

```
# Disable secure_path if set
Defaults !secure_path
```

This should prevent *sudo*, when called with the `--preserve-env` switch, from overriding the PATH environment variable with the value of *secure_path*. And it works as expected.

However, when not using the `--preserve-env` switch, and not prompting a full login sequence with the `--login` switch (thereby not sourcing any of Bash's startup files), and with no assignment to PATH in any of PAM environment files, something strange happens:

```
## Not sure where this PATH value is from, neither from sudo's secure_path option
## (not set), PAM environment files (contain no assignment to PATH), Bash startup
## scripts (not sourced), nor Bash or sshd default PATH values (no match).
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

## Regardless, this is expected
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other which dummy
which: no dummy in (/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)

## But wait! What?!?
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo --user=other dummy
Found!
```

So, how is it that `which dummy` complains of *dummy* not in search path while a straight call to `dummy` without path prefix finds it?

### Relevant Documentation

Following are references to various bits of information that I found relevant while researching this question.

Sudo documentation says this about the *secure_path* option:

> Path used for every command run from sudo. If you don't trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use this. Another use is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user path”. Users in the group specified by the exempt_group option are not affected by secure_path. This option is not set by default.

As per *pam_env* documentation in man pages, only the `/etc/environment`, the `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and `~/.pam_environment` should be processed by the *pam_env* module by default, unless non-default file names are specified. This is not the case on my system and none of these files set or update the value of PATH.

Bash's man page says:

> PATH  The search path for commands. It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND EXECUTION below). A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory. A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon. The default path is system-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash. A common value is “/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin”.

This page of Bash documentation on gnu.org (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) explains when the various startup files are sourced. In my demonstration above, none of these files should be sourced since I'm neither spawning new shells in `--login` or `--interactive`, nor calling *sudo* with the `--login` switch.

This ServerFault answer (https://serverfault.com/questions/833762/where-does-the-bash-path-on-centos-7-get-usr-local-bin-from#answer-838552) explains Bash's default values for the PATH variable. Even though it was answered for Bash on CentOS 7, the answer is still relevant to the Bash version packaged with CentOS 8. As per the accepted answer, the bash source `config-top.h` has this:

```c
/* The default value of the PATH variable. */
#ifndef DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE
#define DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE \
  "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:."
#endif

/* The value for PATH when invoking `command -p'.  This is only used when
   the Posix.2 confstr () function, or CS_PATH define are not present. */
#ifndef STANDARD_UTILS_PATH
#define STANDARD_UTILS_PATH \
  "/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc:/usr/etc"
#endif
```

Comment: Some new information which I had not realized could be relevant: I'm connected to the system through SSH, whose configuration file says that "This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin". I'm not quite sure of what this implies, but there could be a connection, as it contains the /usr/local/bin location. Updating the question with this new information.

Comment: Yet another clue could be given by Bash's default (hard-coded) PATH value which, on the system under consideration, also contains the /usr/local/bin entry. Updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing the interplay between `env_reset` and `secure_path`.

When enabled:

- `secure_path` resets `PATH` to a known-good value
- `env_reset` resets most environment variables, including `PATH` (exact behaviour will depend on other options and configuration, including `secure_path`)

The question is: what does each reset affect?

The second, `env_reset` affects the programs started by `sudo`. On the other hand, `secure_path` also affects `sudo` itself. Without it, `sudo` uses the (calling) user's `PATH` to look up programs. But:

- When starting the program,

  - if `env_reset` is enabled (the default), and

    - `PATH` is not exempt from being reset (e.g., via `env_keep`), then,

      - the program will be started with ...

        - a reset value of `PATH`
        - (as well as other environment variables)

So when you call `which` or `env` or something else, it
won't see the `PATH` that `sudo` itself was using.

Comment: I believe that you are quite right. This comes down to the fact that sudo looks for the target command in the caller's environment, not in the target's. My mistake, I now realize, was to assume that sudo always ran its target command in a shell, although sometimes implicitly (kind of when called with the --login switch, but without the login procedure). Further insights on this aspect of sudo's behavior can be found in the accepted answer to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817693/what-shell-does-sudo-use.